# SMS App with DIFFERENT conversation list style for unreplied threads.

Tags: sms

I've been searching everywhere to find an SMS app where I can see at a glance which conversation threads might need my attention. I often forget to reply to a text and would love to be able to look at my conversation list and see the threads where I was the last person to reply shown in green shading and ones that might be waiting for a reply shown in red. 
I find it ridiculous that all the SMS apps I've tried rely on memory alone (or estimation based on texting style) in order to remember who was the last person to reply. 
I'm a self employed musician and have about 100 contacts that I contact regularly and it takes me ages to go back and check if there's anyone waiting for a reply because I have to open each thread individually. 
It seems like such a simple thing!  You could even have threads highlighted in bright red where the last message was from someone else and it had a "? " in it!

Seriously does anyone know of an app with any distinction between threads like this? 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms). Unread messages have a `NEW` indicator at the top right corner of a conversation. Also, the contact name is usually bold (see screenshot below). You can also select other themes which may have different indicators.

Caveat: There is no way to filter by UNREAD conversations. So, you still have to scroll through them. But the indicator should help a bit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Geff. I tried that. Unfortunately GoSMS pro only makes a distinction between unread and read threads. I usually read a message but forget I hadn't replied!  Looks like I might have to make my own app:( just looking for a way to save time!